# Accessing file system resources using the Apache Sling Resource API

Tags: apache, sling

I want to access the file System using the **sling resource API** . I can access the JCR nodes but not don't know how to access the file System resource . How the **resourceResolver** will resolve the resource objects for filesystem ?

Answer (score 1):

To access filesystem resources a Sling Resources you need to install the `org.apache.sling.fsresource` bundle and create at least one OSGi configuration to activate it.

See the docs at
http://sling.apache.org/documentation/bundles/accessing-filesystem-resources-extensions-fsresource.html